# Will DDoS testing one’s own site negatively impact networks between me and my site?

Tags: load-testing, ddos

I’ve been planning to DDoS test my own site to see the capacity of my site, but gave up at last cause I saw this word of advice:

> DDOS attack does **not** magically reach to the target. It will violate many innocent network infrastructures.

If this is true, then this test means I may even face accusations from those infrastructure providers for the damage to them.

I wonder if this is true, can anyone help me?

Comment: This is not a good idea. The way traffic is routed over the Internet could impact multiple networks, and is surely against the terms of service for your ISP and web host. Use a reputable CDN (many of which are free) to protect your site against DDoS attacks and don't worry about it, that's what they specialize in.

Comment: @dan Sounds like an answer to me! Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc - many stress-test services (which even remain mysterious whether they are legal) on the internet (at least when I Google there's countless at top of the pages) may mislead website owners to "try DDoS their own sites to test traffic capacity". Website owners without much knowledge may suppose the DDoS only affects they themselves. And they will try to use such stress-test services and damage their host against the TOS unintentionally. That's really bad.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! I agree. I was a web host from the very beginning of the Internet. DDoS testing is not something you want to do. I was a consultant for all the major telecoms at the same time. We used to be able to isolate our servers to load test and perform intrusion testing. If you host with a company, you cannot do either. Some of the commercial hosting companies can do this for you. But these hosting options are extremely expensive and not available to the public for general websites. At BT, we continually tested customer sites on our red LAN without issues. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc - So you (or your company) are running your **own** servers, and your **own** hosts. Doing stress-test agreed by you (or your company) will not damage other companies.

Comment: I did own the servers, network, building, etc. I was able to test internally. For myself, just like at BT, I had a green LAN, yellow LAN, red LAN, and black LAN. The green LAN was between the Internet and the environment. The yellow LAN sat behind the first set of firewalls and is the management LAN where the outward facing proxies and services existed. The red LAN was almost completely shutdown and only talked to the yellow LAN servers, proxies, and firewalls. The black LAN connected the servers on the red LAN on the backend for server traffic and did not connect to the red LAN at all.

Comment: @closetnoc - Sorry for the incapability to understand your terms cause I am with really poor knowledge of the web. One important thing I learned from you is that only doing an internal test is suitable, using such services like booters & stressors provided by third-parties are illegal, despite your target or motion. Thanks for helping me understand this! Cheers!!

Comment: Just know that intrusion detection is very common and self-defending networks a reality. So as far as a DDoS is concerned, they are usually ineffective since the better networks can shutdown the unwanted incoming traffic upstream as not to clog the pipe (the connection from the Internet and the host). That was my setup anyway. BTW, I was also directly connected to two NAPs (where Internet backbones connected to each other) and so excessive traffic was never a problem. I got on just one site no less than 100,000 page views per hour. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with comments for one main reason, no one asked how will this DDoS be carried out? If you're planning to use hacked network then yes, it is a bad idea as it puts a lot of stress on the network but also let's face it, 5-10 minutes of heavy traffic never killed anyone.

If you are planning to use AB tools from Apache (follow guide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732182/ab-load-testing) then there is absolutely wrong with it and although it will not show you how the website will perform under real stress it is usually a very good guidance for the website performance.